# how to concatenate objects of an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```
select(dm,i,event){
  let subdomains=dm;
  let index = i;
  let check=event.currentTarget.checked;
   for (var l = 0; l < this.list.length; l++) {
    if(l==i){
     this.list[i].checked=event.currentTarget.checked;
    
    }
  

 }
```

Here from list of an array  like to concatenate domain and subdomain.

domains: Array(8)
{domain: "google.com", subdomain:"www"}
like so make above domain & subdomain after loop over

Comment: I don't see a variable `domains`, but regardless, you could simply use string interpolation: `\`${object.subdomain}.${object.domain}\``.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.map` Operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
domains.map(({domain, subdomain}) => subdomain + domain);
```